# Why Java allows to fire property change when old and new values are null

Tags: java, javabeans

The class `PropertyChangeSupport` fires the `PropertyChangeEvent` when both values (the old and the new) are null. Could somebody explain me what is the reason of this behavior? Some of my colleagues uses this behavior for event driven actions, but I think it's misuse of the property change pattern. Am I right or I misunderstand something?

I mean this line of code:

```
propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(XY_PROPERTY, null, null);
```

Comment: They just seem to use an old bug from the beans package, that allows to do that. Normally when calling with equal values, the event just wouldn't be fired, but specifically for nulls the code I'm seeing reads `if (old == null || new == null || !old.equals(new)) { fire }`. Yes, this looks like a misuse - if you want custom events, you should implement custom events. Unfortunately, Java's event relies on inheritance, and `PropertyChangeSupport` takes up the only slot for `Observable` mechanism. So you can't have both unless your custom events `Observable` should also be-a `PropertyChangeSupport`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks. I've also seen this code. So you think it's a Java bug, that was made to feature (like Microsoft)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, it is philosophical question – null is not a “normal” value, null means “unknown”, and “unknown” can’t be compared with another “unknown”, so if you change the property value from “unknown” to “unknown”, it is a NEW “unknown” value. So similar is it in database - NULL is always unequal to NULL.

From Bean Specification: "Null values may be provided for the old and the new values if their true values are not known.”

Another reason in Bean Specification: “An event source may send a null object as the name to indicate that an arbitrary set of if its properties have changed. In this case the old and new values should also be null."

For more details you can see open jdk issue 4763463 from 2002: (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4763463)

I think, it is not very comfortable for development, but it is so. We can’t change it :-(